# Batch code that will print a list of what is inside the "Recent Items" folder

Tags: batch-file, printing, recent-file-list

I am trying to get a batch code to print the just the Date Modified, and Name of each file (more properties are ok, I just need those two) in the "Recent Items" folder. I have tried a few codes but sadly it will not work, any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dir /T:W "full_path_to_folder"`. Here with the `/T` switch we can force the time field to display (and use for sorting as well): `/T:C` Creation, `/T:A` last Access, `/T:W` last Written (default). Acceptable `/TW` syntax pattern (missing colon) instead of `/T:W`

Comment: Can not get it to work, perhaps I am doing something wrong. my full code looks something like this.                                                           @echo OFF
dir /T:W "C:\Users\White Sign Company\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"

:End
exit

Comment: `exit` will close batch & command window as well. Use `exit /B` or `pause & exit /B`. Also you could redirect output to a file for further use: `dir /T:W "full_path_to_folder" > afile.txt`. There `afile.txt` could be _full path_, e.g. `%temp%\afile.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the sheet idea, I managed to get it to pull up the information, but how to I get it to print it? I tried using "print" but that just made it go on an on

Comment: Redirect output to a file, e.g. `dir > "%temp%\afile.txt"`. [Watch](http://ss64.com/nt/print.html) if `print [/D:device] "%temp%\afile.txt"` command could help, but restricted in print device option to either a local printer (`LPTx`, `COMx`, default `PRN:`) or a network printer by its sharename (`\\servername\print_share`), or `notepad "%temp%\afile.txt"`

Comment: Found `%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE /p "%temp%\afile.txt"` prints a file to default printer (note the `/p` option)

Comment: it worked!!! thank you. it is not very pretty looking however it works. thank you

Comment: @JosefZ it would appear that the file is printed before it is finished loading, is there a way to make it wait till the file is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent items is located here:

`%userprofile%\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`

But it contains only links (`.lnk` files ) to the recent opened items.
So

```
dir /o:d /t:c   "%userprofile%\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
```

Will list them but it will be hard to distinguish files form directories.

Here's how you can get more info with WMIC query (could be slow):

```
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE "PATH='\\Users\\username\\Appdata\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Recent\\'  " GET LastAccessed, LastModified, Name, FileSize
```

Comment: Thank you, but that just makes a pop up come up real quick and then close, really really fast.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @Jwhite try to execute commands in command prompt directly or if its in batch file set `PAUSE` at the end.

Comment: Ok it appears that the batch file has to be in Recent Items folder in order for it to work, which the file will not allow.        When the program runs I get this message: C:\users\white sign company\appdata\romaing\microsoft\windows>dir /o:d /t:c C:\users\white sign company\appdata\romaing\microsoft\windows\recent     The system cannot find teh path specified.

Comment: @Jwhite - there's no need to be there... Put the bath in quotes to be sure that everyting will be ok.

Comment: Manged to get it to pull everything up, but how do I get it to print? tried using /p and print but that just made it run the code over and over and over.

Comment: @Jwhite what you meam with print? To write it to a file?

Comment: send the information that I just pull up to the printer

Comment: @Jwhite - you need to output the command output to a file (e.g. `command>textfile.txt`) and then with print command http://ss64.com/nt/print.html

Comment: Recent items location could be found by `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v recent`. Could result to slightly different value than _npocmaka_ refer to, e.g. to "%userprofile%\Recent"

Comment: @JosefZ - I've found the location through .net - `import System;Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent));`

Comment: thank you the location seems more functional. I got it to work. It is not exactly pretty looking but it will do what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Taking regard to all *chat-like* discussion:

`1.` To get "recent" folder:

```
`For /F "tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v recent ^|Find /I "recent"') do @echo G="%%G" H="%%H" I="%%I"`
```

and then you could replace that `@echo G="%%G" H="%%H" I="%%I"` with `set "recentfldr=%%I"` and continue with `dir "%recentfldr%\"` etc.

`2.` To wait until `dir` command ends (add switches for `dir` *ad libitum* but note escaped redirecting operator `^>`):

```
start "" /wait cmd /C dir /s "%recentfldr%\" ^> "%temp%\afile.txt"
```

`3.` To send a text file to default printer:

`%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE /p "%temp%\afile.txt"`

Good luck!